# Prove this number fact

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Prove that $x \neq 0,y \neq 0 \Rightarrow xy \neq 0$.

Suppose $xy = 0$. Then $\frac{xy}{xy} = 1$. Can we say that $\frac{xy}{xy} = 0$ and hence $1 = 0$ which is a contradiction? I thought $\frac{0}{0}$ was undefined.

Comment: Proofs that have 0 in the denominator are usually suspect!

Comment: This proof completely depends on the axioms you choose to use, as in some universes this implication does not hold (e.g. $\mathbb{Z}_n$, where n is not prime$)

Comment: As has been explained, the proposed argument is not right.  To help you with an appropriate proof, one needs context. For what kind of numbers? What kind of course?

Comment: @Qia No, his hypothesis is $x,y\ne 0\:.$ It's a proof by contradiction - see my answer.

Comment: @GEdgar The proof is correct - see my answer.

Comment: @André See my answer.

Comment: Re-tagged, as I think this is more algebra than number theory.

Comment: Bill Dubuques answer is the one I want.

Comment: Could you please tell us about the source of the proof. Was it a proof that you found somewhere or one that you were attempting to construct based on a hint, or perhaps something altogether different?

Comment: @Bill Dubuque: It was in Rudin's principles of math analysis. I was trying to prove it and the proof there was basically the same as mine.

Comment: If it's not too much trouble to tell me precisely where it is in Rudin I'd be grateful to know.

Comment: The way to indicate which answer you want is to click in the little check mark to the left of it.

Comment: @Bill Dubuque: Your proof is very attractive. But if integers have just been introduced semi-axiomatically, a considerable amount of work needs to be done before your proof becomes available.  But one can prove the result the OP wants without additional conceptual apparatus.

Comment: @André The context is rudimentary properties of a field, Prop. 1.16 in Rudin's PMA, see below. No considerable work is needed, only a general notation for inverses - see my comments to Asaf below. I had no luck explaining it to Asaf there, so I'm curious if it is comprehensible to you. I'd like to improve the answer but I'm not sure what is the true source of confusion for many. If you could lend any insight on this I'd be most grateful.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The proof is valid in any field $\rm\: K$ (though it might be circular depending on the context). Namely, $\rm\:0\ne x,y\in K\:$ $\:\Rightarrow\:$ $\rm\: 1/x,1/y\in K\:$ $\:\Rightarrow\:$ $\rm\:(1/x)(1/y) = 1/(xy)\in K\:$ $\:\Rightarrow\:$ $\rm\:xy\ne 0\:.$ The OP's proof is simply this proof recast into a proof by contradiction. To be precise the OP's proof is as follows:

As above, $\rm\: x,y\ne 0\ \Rightarrow\ z := 1/(xy)\in K\:,\:$ i.e. $\rm\:xyz = 1\:.\:$ So $\rm\ xy=0\ \Rightarrow\ 0 = 1\:,\:$ a contradiction.

That's *precisely* the OP's proof, except I've replaced $\rm\:xy/(xy)\:$  by $\rm\:xyz\:$ to avoid possible confusion.

This is a valid proof. The confusion stems from the fact that it is a proof by *contradiction*. Such proofs - by their very nature - may encounter all sorts of strange looking mathematical objects, such as the above expression of the form $\rm\: 0/0 = 1\:.\:$ This is just $\rm\:1/1 = 1\:$ in the trivial ring $\:\{0\}\:$ where $\rm\:0 = 1\:.\:$ However, the trivial ring is not a field, since $\rm\:0\ne 1\:$ by the definition of a field (or integral domain). So, as above, $\rm\:0 = 1\:$ is a common target for proofs by contradiction in a field.

Proofs by contradiction often prove immensely confusing to students when first encountered. Learning to wrap one's mind around the bizarre contradictory objects encountered in such proofs is skill that comes with practice. A striking example of such confusion is Euclid's classical proof that there are infinitely many primes. Although Euclid's proof was constructive, it is widely presented as a proof by contradiction (and falsely claimed that this was Euclid's proof). When presented in contradictory form this proof often leads to much confusion. There are hundreds of threads on sci.math permeated by such confusion. One can reach all sorts of contradictions to terminate Euclid's proof, e.g. $\rm\:0 = 1\:$ or $\rm\: 1\:$ is prime, or some integer is both prime and composite, etc. Indeed, one can deduce anything in a contradictory theory such as the integers with finitely many primes. Such contradictions often prove too much to grasp for many beginners. Apparently this is because  we have such strong intuition about integers that one contradiction easily implies many others, and this quickly grows too much to handle intuitively. This does not occur to the same degree when one works with more abstract structures, where real-world intuition has less chance to restrain logical thought processes. Such is the strange nature of proofs by contradiction.

**Note** $\ $ The OP has revealed the source as Proposition 1.16 in Rudin's *Principles of Mathematial Analysis*. I've appended it below. It is essentially as I surmised above.[image]

Comment: I don't think that's what OP had in mind...

Comment: @anon Only the OP can say what they "had in mind". My point is that the above is one valid way of viewing it.

Comment: The second proof you have isn't like the first one nor the OP.  In the first one, you can start with the hypothesis that x does not equal 0 and y does not equal 0, which basically implies the rest.  In the second one, if x, y does not equal 0, then xy is not equal to 0, and thus xy=0 is false (given a two-valued logic).  Though such a proof ends up valid, if xy=0 gets taken as a hypothesis along with that x, y does not equal 0, it simply doesn't work out as consistent throughout, while *just* having a hypothesis of x, y not equal to 0 does work out as consistent (or at least not inconsistent).

Comment: @Doug What you wrote above shows confusion about the nature of proofs by contradiction. Comments are too short for a tutorial on such. Perhaps you might consider posing a new question about such.

Comment: @Bill, assuming $xy=0$ means that one cannot write $\frac{z}{xy}$ validly, since only numbers which are nonzero have an inverse. If you can write $\frac{z}{xy}$ then you assume that $xy\neq 0$ implicitly.

Comment: @Asaf Not true. The above proof is correct. If you do in fact believe that the proof is incorrect then please state *precisely* which inference you think is incorrect and I'll be happy to set you straight. Beware that proofs by contradiction, by their nature, require extra care to comprehend correctly.

Comment: @Bill The proof in the OP has xy=0.  This happens as a *supposition*.  It doesn't get inferred.  Your proof *infers* to the conditional "xy=0 => 0=1".  The antecedent of that conditional isn't true in the presence of x and y both not equal to 0.  The supposition of xy=0 works fine in the OP.  However, from that you can't infer that for a *consistent* field xy/(xy)=1, as the OP tries to do, since division by 0 is not defined in a consistent field. You haven't done that. You don't have that xy/xy=1 *for all* elements of the field as the OP suggests.  You only have that for the non-zero elements.

Comment: @Bill Asaf didn't say either of the above proof wasn't correct.  I haven't claimed either incorrect also.  However, the first proof still comes as dissimilar to the first proof you gave.  It does hold that xy=0 means you can't write z/(xy) validly from the assumption of consistency.  A field does not define division *for all* elements of the field, but only *nonzero* elements.  This "x,y≠0 ⇒ z:=1/(xy)∈K, i.e. xyz=1" doesn't claim otherwise, since the antecedent implies xy as a nonzero element.

Comment: The way I originally understood OP, the two cornerstones of his proof are that $a/a=1$ and $0/a=0$ unilaterally for all $a$ (these are not sound assumptions, as they don't make sense with $a=0$). I wouldn't be surprised if OP *did*, in fact, have your specific reasoning in mind, but I see no actual evidence of it in the question. And while your proof by contradiction is obviously valid, I think the confusion here is whether or not it's a faithful interpretation of the OP. Since @Numberguy hasn't responded I say the point is moot for the time being.

Comment: @Bill You're simply wrong that I'm confused here, and at best even if I were you've only *guessed* at that instead of providing evidence or a discussion as to where my confusion lies.  In truth, you're the one here who comes as confused, and as I've pointed out your confusion lies in thinking the proofs fundamentally similar and confusion a supposition and an inference, with a conditional.  In logic, this is like confusing "p|-q" with "|- Cpq" which compares to confusing the object language with the metalanguage.  This *can* get remedied by comments and discussion.

Comment: @anon This is a common proof by contradiction in field theory - one might even say a *prototypical* proof. I suspect that the OP was puzzled by one of these proofs, and paraphrased it here in his question. That fits perfectly with how the question is presented above. I see no other sensical way to interpret the question.

Comment: @Doug There is nothing wrong with my proof. The only possible point of contention is the metamathematical matter of whether or not the proof the OP intends to discuss is the one I present or something else. I don't think the latter alternative is plausible given the way the question is presented.

Comment: This is why I think my interpretation is the most sensible and parsimonious: (1) The number of people aware of the basic algebraic rules $a/a=1$ and $0/a=0$ *vastly* outnumbers the number of people who can do a fleshed out proof by contradiction. (2) The OP includes every step that is from my interpretation, and includes 0 steps from alternative interpretations to distinguish otherwise. (3) A valid textbook proof by contradiction would be difficult to "paraphrase" in the way OP wrote the question, as the expression $\frac{xy}{xy}$ would not be present without any explanation or lead-in.

Comment: @anon The first two sentences of the OP's question make it absolutely clear that it is a proof by contradiction. I'm baffled why anyone would think otherwise. Given that it is a proof by contradiction, I can see no other logical way to interpret the proposed proof other than as I explained above.

Comment: @anon (3) is easily explained. The OP could be attempting to understand a textbook proof such as that I presented above. To attempt to understand it, he eliminates $z$ by replacing it by $1/(xy)$ and notices that this yields $xy/(xy)$ leading to the $0/0$ confusion. It makes perfect sense.

Comment: Let me clarify: I do not believe OP's proof is not a proof by contradiction, I believe it is one that is not as *fleshed out* as yours. Specifically, my interpretation of OP's proof is $$(1)\quad a/a=1 \implies \frac{xy}{xy}=1,$$ $$(2)\quad 0/a\implies \frac{xy}{xy}=\frac{0}{xy}=0,$$ $$(3)\quad 1=0.$$ Both our interpretations agree with OP's on the initial hypotheses and (3), but only my interpretation explicitly includes what OP said for (1) and (2).

Comment: @Bill Dubuque: It is proposition 1.16 in rudin. Can someone please convert this into a comment? Also I would like to accept Bill's answer but can't seem to check it.

Comment: @Numberguy: I have merged your duplicate account with the one you used to ask the question. You should now be able to accept Bill's answer by clicking the green check mark that is on the upper left of his answer.

Comment: @Asaf Do you still believe your above comment is correct? If so, I'd be grateful if you could please elaborate. I've always been fascinated by cognitive hurdles encountered in comprehending proofs by contradiction.

Comment: @Bill: Yes. I still think my comment as stated is true. The expression $\frac{0}{0}$ is invalid in any context. The same way I could write "Proof that $\pi=3$ by contradiction: Assume $\frac{0}{0}=1$, therefore: $$\pi=\pi\cdot 1 =\frac{\pi\cdot 0}{0} = \frac{0}{0}=\frac{3\cdot 0}{0}=3\cdot 1=3$$ The point is that if you *assume* that $xy=0$ then you *cannot* write $\frac{xy}{xy}$ in a meaningful way without intentionally introducing a false statement into your proof. You can, however, write $$xy=0\implies x^{-1}xy=x^{-1}\cdot 0\implies y=0$$

Comment: @Asaf $xy/(xy) = xy(1/x)(1/y)$ is well-defined: by hypothesis, $0 \ne x,y\in K$ so, by field axioms, they have inverses $1/x, 1/y$. So $xy(1/x)(1/y)$ is a product of $4$ elements of $K$. It's well-defined because multiplication is a *total* function. The proof by contradiction proceeds by hypothesizing additionally that $xy=0$. That one can now deduce myriad contradictions is not a bug, but rather a feature of proof by contradiction. In this case we even have a *model* where the proof may be interpreted, viz. the zero ring $\{0\}$ where $0 = 1$ so $ 0/0 = 1/1 = 1$

Comment: @Bill: Note that Rudin does not write $\frac{xy}{xy}$. Was he trying to extend his proof to consume more paper and damage the rain forests? I doubt that. Yes, the contradiction is indeed in the fact that one derives $0=1$. The point is that one derives it from writing $1=xy\frac{1}{x}\frac{1}{y}=0$, not from writing an invalid (except in the zero ring) expression as $\frac{0}{0}$.

Comment: @Asaf At issue isn't Rudin's proof but, rather, the OP's reinterpretation in terms of $xy/(xy)\:.\:$ To interpret the OP's proof I employ a notation for inverses that works *universally*, i.e. in all rings, including the zero ring, viz. in *any* commutative ring if $\ rs = 1\ $ then $1/r$ denotes $s$, the inverse of $r$ (necessarily unique). So in the proof since $xy(1/y)(1/x) = 1$ we may write $1/(xy)$ for $1/y\ 1/x$ in Rudin's proof, whch yields the OP's reinterpretation, after using the definition that $a/b = a(1/b)$ so $xy/(xy) = xy\ 1/(xy)$. There is nothing "invalid" about that.

Comment: @Asaf That $0/0$ is invalid in rings except $0$ isn't relevant since the ring in the proof *is* $0$. It's akin to this. Consider this form of Euclid's classical proof of infinitely many primes: if $p_1,\ldots,p_n$ are all the primes then $1 < 1 + p_1\cdots p_n$ has no smaller prime factor so is prime, contra hypothesis. Some claim this is invalid since $1+2\cdot 3\cdots 13 = 59 \cdot 509$, so the proof does *not* construct a prime. That is not a valid objection since the proof does not work in N. Rather, it works in the *hypothetical* object $\ll$ N with a finite number of primes $\gg$.

Comment: @Bill: The issue here that you appeal to the Rudin proof and claim the two are the same. They are not. Please do not interpret my lack of further response here as agreement with any of the points you have made so far.

Comment: @Asaf The "sameness" of the proofs is not what we were discussing. Rather, we were discussing your (false) claims in your first two comments that my proof uses expressions "invalid in any context". Hopefully what I wrote above makes it clear that this is not true. The point of my proof is simply that the OP's reinterpretation of Rudin's proof *can be made rigorous* - in a manner that is quite natural algebraically, contra the many *unfounded* objections elsewhere on this web page.

Comment: @Bill: While my interpretation seemed to me to have the better backing, and public support, it turns out in the end that you are in the right. Kudos.

Comment: To me the main point here is that not enough care is taken to write _exactly_ the right expressions; in the very early stage of theory we cannot write one expression for another because they can (later!) be proven equivalent (and we have the habit of normalising the form immediately). Notable, after "To be precise", one cannot replace $(\frac1x)(\frac1y)$ from Rudin's proof by $\frac1{xy}$. The field axioms allow writing $a^{-1}$ for any _nonzero_ $a$ (and $b/a$ means $ba^{-1}$). So writing $\frac1{xy}$ requires having $xy\ne0$ as fact or assumption; not the case here. But Rudin's form is OK.

Comment: Similarly, the second line of this answer would be fine if $(1/x)(1/y) = 1/(xy)$ (which again suffers from taking the inverse of a number not known to be nonzero) were replaced by $(1/x)(1/y)xy=1$ (which has no such problem, and contradicts with $xy=0$ as desired).

Answer (score 4):

The fault occurs immediately: "Suppose $xy=0$. Then $\frac{xy}{xy}=1$." This is not true, as the property $\frac{a}{a} = 1$ holds only when $ a\neq 0 $, and we have just assumed that $xy$ is indeed $0$.

However, we can still go along the road of contraction. Suppose $xy=0$. By assumption $x\neq 0 $ so we may divide $xy$ by $x$ to obtain $y=0$, which is in contraction with the other assumption that $y\neq 0$.

Comment: No, the proof is correct if viewed appropriately. See my answer.

Comment: I think the OP just wrote the "suppose" line too soon, which is the cause for the confusion. "It is given that $x \neq 0$, $y \neq 0$. So $\frac{xy}{xy} = 1$. Suppose $xy=0$. Then we get a contradiction <somehow> (e.g., because $\frac{xy}{xy}=1$ is not true for $xy=0$)." Something along these lines is the proof the OP seems to have been reaching for.

Comment: @Shr That's not the problem. Every proof by contradiction starts that way. Rather, the problem is that proofs by contradiction can be very difficult to comprehend when the negated statement contradicts facts that are deeply hardwired into our intuition. The large number of erroneous votes here are witness to that, along with many hundreds of analogous erroneous posts on other math forums, e.g. sci.math.

Answer (score 0):

If xy=0, then x=0 or y=0.  So, by contraposition, if is not the case that "x=0 OR y=0", then it is not the case that xy=0.  By De Morgan's Laws, we have that "if it is not the case that x=0 AND it is not the case that y=0, then it is not the case that xy=0".  Now we move the negations around as a "quantifier exchange" and we have "if x is not equal to 0 and y is not equal to 0, then xy is not equal to 0."

If xy=0, we can't say that xy/xy=1.  Division doesn't exist in the rational numbers.  It *only* exists in non-zero rational numbers, or if you prohibit 0 in any denominator.  xy/xy=1 only on the condition that "/" is defined.  So this "Suppose xy=0. Then xy/xy=1." isn't correct.

Answer (score -1):

consider that `xy=0` from the  basic  axioms we know that  product is zero  when  at least one of the  multiplier is  zero  so is means that  x is zero or y is zero  or both x and y is equal zero  which contradicts  to given condition that neither x or y is zero so it means that their product is also  not equal to zero

Comment: "$A$ when $B$" means "$B\Rightarrow A$", yet you are treating this as though it were "$A\Rightarrow B$," a logical fallacy.

Comment: @jwodder actually the original statement says "$x\neq 0 \land y\neq 0 \implies xy \neq 0$, and this post attempts to prove $xy = 0 \implies x = 0\lor y = 0$ which is perfectly equivalent (although he seems to be saying things about contradiction which is unnecessary)  and hence not a logical fallacy

Answer (score -1):

Sorry the answer is a bit late, but I just saw this post and happened to have Rudin's book on me so I've taken a look at the proposition the OP was referring to.

1.16 (b) If $x\neq 0$ and $y\neq 0$ then $xy \neq 0$.

the proof essentially goes as follows

Suppose $x\neq 0$ and $y\neq 0$, and suppose for contradiction that $xy = 0$. Since $x, y\neq 0$ we know that $\frac{1}{x}, \frac{1}{y}\in F$, Hence $1 = (\frac{1}{x})(\frac{1}{y})xy = (\frac{1}{x})(\frac{1}{y})0 = 0$ a contradiction.

The fallacy given in the OP is that since we assume that $xy = 0$ we cannot write $\frac{xy}{xy}$ because we are clearly dividing by zero. However, we can write $(\frac{1}{x})(\frac{1}{y})$ because we know both are in the field (and hence their product is as well) since $x, y \neq 0$.

I hope this helps even though it's late

Comment: There is no "fallacy". The expression $(xy)/(xy)$ denotes $xy(xy)^{-1} = xyz$. See my answer.

Comment: @Bill Dubuque I see you're answer and I agree that your proof is correct, I simply answered because I went to see the proof in Rudin and hoped another post may address confusion the OP had that may have stemmed from the proof he laid out there