# Field axioms: Why do we have $ 1 \neq 0$?

Tags: field-theory, definition

In the definitions of a field, we have $ 1 \neq 0$.

I know that in regular multiplication $0 \times 1=0$ but for reciprocal we don't have inverse of $0$.

But all the spaces and different definitions of multiplications that are satisfying field axioms, why do we need $ 1 \neq 0$?

Please do not use too technical of terminology. I am reading Baby Rudin right now.

Comment: This does not follow from the other axioms.  But we do not want to count the ring $\{0\}$ as a field.  So add that extra axiom to rule it out.

Comment: Hi and welcome on Math.SE! Does it feel better to say that _identity elements for  multiplication and addition must be distinct_?

Comment: Dupe of [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/634783/2420) and probably others.

Answer (score 8):

As pointed out already in another answer, a ring in which $1=0$ just consists of a single element as for example 
$$a=1a=0a=(0+0)a = (1+1)a= a+a$$ 
shows $0=a$ for each $a$.

**And,** one does not want this structure, just $\{0\}$, to be a field, since this would be inconvenient, since then on would one would write all the time let $K$ be a field other than the trivial field, instead of just writing let $K$ be a field.

For example, there is no reasonable notion of a (non-trivial) vectorspace over that "field" so what is $K^2,K^3$ and so on in that case? Again the trivial vectorspace, but then the dimension of $K^n$ is not $n$ anymore for this "field".

Polynomials over that ring make not much sense either and one can continue in this way.

Comment: so distributive law binds them all

Comment: so that is alreay implied, why to mention $1 \neq 0$ in axioms

Comment: so you are saying in trivial field, when everything is equal to each other, there is no discrimination among elements,  1≠0 can be relaxed

Comment: Yes mainly it is the distributive law, and then also the fact that it is a group under addition. What I mean to say is that if one drops the axiom $1 \neq 0$, then one gets *only* one more structure that is a field. Every field $K$ with $|K| \ge 2$ will automatically have $0 \neq 1$. The $1 \neq 0$ is really just another way to say $|K|\ge 2$.

Comment: i thought it would be ideal, simple to show a few characteristics of the field, simple yet to grasp the meaning. A good example

Answer (score 3):

If $1 = 0$, the field is only $\Bbb K = \{0\}$. $$x = x \cdot 1 = x \cdot 0 = 0, \quad \forall\, x \in \Bbb K$$

Comment: if 1=0 then this holds, this does not necessarily excludes 1=0. zero do not necessaril set 0 all elements

Comment: I'm not sure I follow your doubt now. Can you elaborate?

Comment: in axioms, there is no x.0=0 rule, so why do above argument requires $1 \neq 0$

Comment: @aileia You can prove that $x\cdot 0=0$ in any ring by $$x\cdot 0=x\cdot (1-1)=x-x=0.$$

Comment: That's what Joe said. And if you want to be $100\%$ rigorous, you'll want to prove that $(-1)\cdot x = -x$ in any ring, too.

Comment: so you are saying, x.0 =0 is implied in axioms by distributive law

Comment: Yes, you can prove it from the axioms, like Joe did in his last comment.

Comment: what if -1 cannot interact x, according to my multiplication definition, but only with 1, it wil not equal to 0?

Comment: From the axioms, you can prove that $ (-1) \cdot x = - x $. Any field element interacts with $ x $ via the scalar multiplication operation.

Comment: I think i can do that:) by distributive law.:) (1+(-1))*x=0 implies -1*x=-x

Answer (score 0):

If 1=0, by definition of these two elements, one would have, for every element $a$ of this "field,"  $a=1a=0a=0$ as @quid has shown, in other words the ground set for this field would simply be a singleton. So there would be not much excitement or usefulness in this field. It is like lack of excitement in considering log base 1 -- it is no fun, or for that matter considering 1 to be a prime number.