# The characteristic of an integral domain is not equal to 1

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I need help with the following:

> Let $R$ be a ring that is also an integral domain, such that its characteristic is not zero. Let $n \in \mathbb{N}$ be the characteristic of $R$. Show that $n \neq 1$.

Since $R$ is NOT of characteristic $0$, then (in the notation of my Algebra class) we have $o_{R^{+}}=1$. Here $o_{R^{+}}=1$ is the order of $1$ as an element of the additive group $(R, +)$. So for $R$ a positive integer $k$ exists such that $k \cdot a = 0$ for all $ a \in R$, and in this case $n$ is the least such positive integer, so $n\cdot a=0$. By $n \cdot a$, I mean: $(a+ a+...+ a)$ $n$-times.

Now by way of contradiction, suppose $n=1$, then $1\cdot a=0$. So $1=0$ or $a=0$. But $1 \neq 0$, so  $a=0$. How can I come to a contradiction? Is $a \neq 0$?

Comment: if $n=1$ wouldnt everything just collapse into $0$?

Comment: The common convention is that $1\neq 0$ in integral domains, i,e. $\{0\}$ is not a domain. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/634783/242) for discussion of this convention.